# Prevent vscode node debugger from showing node_modules code

Tags: node.js, debugging, visual-studio-code, node-modules

I'm trying to debug a really complex [Angular 9 app in VSCode using Node Debugger, browser-preview and Debugger for Chrome](https://medium.com/@MarkPieszak/debugging-angular-cli-inside-vscode-with-browser-preview-8dcc4b18ed64), and the debugger leading me to node_module internal code constantly is driving me crazy.

I've tried using both `Browser Preview: Launch` and `ng serve` [with this VSCode skipFiles configuration](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging#_skipping-uninteresting-code-node-chrome) but the first one keeps entering node_modules, and the later is only trying to start Chrome *after* I cancel the debugging process. (which seems like a totally unrelated problem to the current topic, but I would like any opinions on that part if you feel like it)

I've already sent an issue to the maker of the `browser-preview` extension, since VSCode is giving me a `Property not allowed` warning with `skipFiles`. If anyone finds a problem and/or has a suggestion for the following launch.json, will be appreciated.

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "browser-preview",
            "name": "Browser Preview: Attach",
            "request": "attach"
        },
        {
            "type": "browser-preview",
            "request": "launch",
            "preLaunchTask": "npm: start",
            "name": "Browser Preview: Launch",
            "url": "http://localhost:4200",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "skipFiles": [
                "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/**/*.js",
                "<node_internals>/**/*.js"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "ng serve",
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "preLaunchTask": "npm: start",
            "url": "http://localhost:4200/",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "skipFiles": [
                "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/**/*.js",
                "<node_internals>/**/*.js"
            ],
            "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
                "webpack:/*": "${webRoot}/*",
                "/./*": "${webRoot}/*",
                "/src/*": "${webRoot}/*",
                "/*": "*",
                "/./~/*": "${webRoot}/node_modules/*"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

[image]

EDIT: *My objective is to **avoid breakpoint spamming**, by using "Step Into (F11)" and "Step Over (F10)" to navigate the code line by line, and "Continue (F5)" to jump to the next breakpoint when needed.*

Comment: You could try `"/node_modules/**/*.js"` from https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-chrome-debug/issues/634

Comment: @Mark nope, both "Step Over" and "Step Into" are still getting into node_modules code (http, promise, observable and the like).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The warning is a Typescript level bug, and it does not affects in any way the compilation. 
Everything works as intended after thoroughly testing it with the following dependency set:

```
"@types/node": "^13.7.7",
"@angular/cli": "^9.0.5",
"@angular/compiler": "^9.0.5",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^9.0.5",
"ts-node": "^8.6.2",
"tslint": "^6.0.0",
"typescript": "^3.7.5",
...
```